# Adding async functions in `criterion_group!()` macro

Tags: rust, benchmarking, rust-cargo, rust-criterion

In [Criterion's documentation](https://bheisler.github.io/criterion.rs/book/user_guide/benchmarking_async.html), there is plenty of information on how to benchmark asynchronous functions, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to run an async function that exists *outside* of the function I'm attempting to benchmark. The basic idea is this:

```rust
pub async fn benchmark_inputs(c: &mut Criterion) {
    // function that gathers inputs is async
    // it also would be redundant to retrieve this info in the benchmark `.iter()` every time.
    // the below code does not work with either block_on() or .await
    let inputs = block_on(get_inputs());


    c.bench_function("benchmark_inputs_that_match", |b| {
        b.iter(|| {
            func_to_benchmark(inputs) // this function is _not_ async
        })
    });
}
```

The code above has no warnings or errors in the Rust analyzer, but when you try to add this to the `criterion_group`, you get a warning:

```rust
criterion_group!(
    benches,
    benchmark_inputs,
);
criterion_main!(benches);
```

This does not work, as there is an `unused implementer of futures::Future that must be used futures do nothing unless you .await or poll them` warning.

Ignoring the warning and running `cargo bench` will technically work, but there is no timing information or HTML reports generated as usual, so it is useless.

Has anyone else come across this issue?

Comment: Do not make `benchmark_inputs_that_match()` `async`, and use `block_on()`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman This results in a thread panic: `there is no reactor running, must be called from the context of a Tokio 1.x runtime`. I have the async_tokio feature enabled in Criterion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a nudge from [Chayim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7884305/chayim-friedman), I found a way to make this work (although it's not my favorite to have `mut` variables):

I created a `mut`able `inputs` variable, then created a tokio runtime to retrieve the inputs in:

```rust
pub async fn benchmark_inputs(c: &mut Criterion) {
    // function that gathers inputs is async
    // it also would be redundant to retrieve this info in the benchmark `.iter()` every time.
    // the below code does not work with either block_on() or .await
    let mut inputs = Vec::new()

    let runtime = tokio::runtime::Builder::new_current_thread()
        .build()
        .unwrap();

    runtime.block_on(async {
        inputs = get_inputs().await;
    });


    c.bench_function("benchmark_inputs_that_match", |b| {
        b.iter(|| {
            func_to_benchmark(inputs) // this function is _not_ async
        })
    });
}
```